# Spatial SQL query showing parcels containing centroid of building

Tags: sql, spatial-query, parcel, oracle-spatial, centroid

I am trying to write a query that selects parcels that *contain the centroid* of a certain building code (bldg_code = 3).

The parcels are listed in the table "city.zoning" and contains a column for a PIN, geometry, and area of each parcel. The table "buildings" contains a column for bldg_type and bldg_code indicating the building type and its corresponding code. The building type of interest for this query has a bldg_code of 3.

So far I've developed a query that shows parcels that *interact* with the building type of interest:

```
select a.*
from city.zoning a, username.buildings b
where b.bldg_code = 3 and sdo_anyinteract(a.geom,b.geom) = 'TRUE';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SDO_GEOM.SDO_CENTROID` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objgeom.htm#i860848)) to find the centroid of a geometry.

Note that the centroid provided by this function is the mathematical centroid only and may not always lie *inside* the geometry, for example, if your polygon is L shaped. SpatialDB Adviser has [a good article on this](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/71/oracle-spatial-centroid-shootout), but here's a quick illustration:

[image: Centroid laying outside its parent geometry]

If this isn't a problem for you and you don't need that level of accuracy, just use the built-in, but if you do consider this to be a problem (as I did in the past), then SpatialDB Adviser has [a standalone PL/SQL package that corrrectly calculates centroids](http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/228/standalone-centroid-package-now-available-for-download).

Depending on your performance needs, you could calculate the centroids on-the-fly and just use them in your query directly, or alternatively, add a centroid column to the table and compute and cache the values with application code (best case) or trigger (worst case).

Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM city.zoning a
JOIN username.buildings b ON sdo_contains(a.geom, b.centroid) = 'TRUE'
WHERE b.bldg_code = 3
```

Note that this is using `SDO_CONTAINS` on the basis of the `a.geom` column being spatially indexed and a new column `b.centroid` that has been added and populated (note - query not tested). If the zoning geometry is not spatially indexed, then you would need to use `SDO_GEOM.RELATE`, or index the centroid column and invert the logic to use `SDO_INSIDE`.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you for your help!